# R DPLYR GROUPINGS

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

data(mtcars)

mtcars$FACTORA = sample(c("A", "b"), r=T)
```

mtcars$FACTORB=sample("c","e")

```
DATA = mtcars %>%
  group_by(FACTORA, FACTORB) %>%
  slice(which.min(wt)) &
  group_by(FACTORA) %>%
  slice(which.min(wt))
```

I wish to keep rows that MINIMIZE wt by qsec and gear and also keep rows that minimize wt just by qsec all in one data.

or do i have to do this

```
DATA = mtcars %>%
  group_by(FACTORA,FACTORB) %>%
  slice(which.min(wt))

DATADATA = mtcars %>%
  group_by(FACTORA) %>%
  slice(which.min(wt))
```

and then do merge?

[image]

Comment: `qsec` is numeric.  I guess your group by is incorrect `n_distinct(mtcars$qsec)#
[1] 30` perhaps `mtcars %>% arrange(gear, qsec, wt) %>% distinct(gear, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun i just use as a example my actual data is factors

Comment: Try the `arrange` method  with slight change `mtcars %>% arrange(qsec, gear, wt) %>% distinct(qsec, gear, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: As your example is not mimicking the  original data, it is not clear about your expected

Comment: @akrun my expected is to get MIN value for SCORE variable by FACTOR-A and FACTOR-B as well as overall MIN value for SCORE variable OVERALL (not by another grouping variables)

Comment: Can you please update your post with a small example and its expected

Comment: @akrun how about now

Comment: Sorry, your expected output is not clear.  Also, the input data created with sample wihtout set.seed.  `mtcars %>% group_by(FACTORA) %>% mutate(minwt_factA = min(wt)) %>% group_by(FACTORB, .add = TRUE) %>% mutate(minwt_factAB =min(wt)) %>% ungroup` (creates two columns with minwt)

Comment: @akrun i add a picture now does this help??

Comment: I am guessing that you need `cube` or `rollup` from `data.table` i.e. `rollup(dt1, j = lapply(.SD, min), by = c("FACTORA", "FACTORB"), .SDcols="wt")` where `dt1 <- as.data.table(mtcars)`

Comment: @bvowe, keeping minimum in a group of two will keep the minimum in a group of one.  Won't it? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean (replacing `qsec` for `cyl` which is categorical). Note that in this set of groupings the `keep2` is a bit extraneous since any row that minimizes `wt` for each `cyl` is guaranteed to appear in the rows that minimize `wt` for each `cyl`/`gear` group.

Also, this will only return one minimum and drop ties, though since you use `which.min` above I figure that isn't important.

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
  arrange(wt) %>%
  mutate(keep1 = row_number() == 1L) %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  arrange(wt) %>% 
  mutate(keep2 = row_number() == 1L) %>%
  filter(keep1 | keep2)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 13
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb keep1 keep2
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77  1.51  16.9     1     1     5     2 TRUE  TRUE 
#> 2  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2 TRUE  FALSE
#> 3  21.5     4 120.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1 TRUE  FALSE
#> 4  21       6 160     110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 TRUE  TRUE 
#> 5  19.7     6 145     175  3.62  2.77  15.5     0     1     5     6 TRUE  FALSE
#> 6  15.8     8 351     264  4.22  3.17  14.5     0     1     5     4 TRUE  TRUE 
#> 7  21.4     6 258     110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1 TRUE  FALSE
#> 8  15.2     8 304     150  3.15  3.44  17.3     0     0     3     2 TRUE  FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: i update the question